# How to display a table using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Just stared learning CodeIgniter (using v3.1.7). I have this table called **training**.
[image]

I followed the steps described in [this tutorial](http://avenir.ro/codeigniter-retrieve-data-from-database/):

First, create a model called training_model.php (put it in **/application/models**)

```
<?php

    class training_model extends CI_Model {

        function get_all_trainings(){

            $q = $this->db->get('training');

            if($q->num_rows() > 0){

            foreach ($q->result() as $row){
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }

?>
```

Then create it's controller (training.php), put in **/application/controllers**.

```
<?php
if(!defined("BASEPATH")) exit("No direct script access allowed");

class training extends CI_Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    $this->load->model("training_model"); 
    $data["trainings"]=$this->users_model->get_all_trainings(); 

    $this->load->view("users_view", $data);
  }
}
```

Last one is the view (training_view.php), put it into **/application/views**

```
<?php

if (!empty($trainings)){
    foreach ($trainings as $t){
        echo $t->eventName .' '. $t->eventDescription.' '.$t->eventDate.' '.$t->eventVenue;
    }
}

?>
```

How to access the view from the browser, so I can see the database's content?

Comment: to pick up the basics of CI this is a good read: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html

Comment: go to your base_url + /training on localhost: "localhost/training"

Comment: CI3 needs {controller,model,library} file and class name in ucfirst() way. Capitalize first letter there.

Comment: First of all, you need to read your code and understand what it is trying to do... You've managed to rename the files from the "tutorial" but can you see where you haven't. Hint: everywhere you've left the name "users", it should be changed to training.

Comment: Plus, you've not followed the naming rules... Classes need to be first letter uppercase, the same goes for their filenames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your site was `example.com` then the url

```
http://example.com/training
```

should work.

You need to implement an `.htaccess` file for the above to work. Without `.htaccess` you would need this url

```
http://example.com/index.php/training
```

Read about removing the index.php file from the URL [HERE](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html?highlight=htaccess#removing-the-index-php-file).